# How can I replace outliers with maximum non-outlier value?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, anomaly-detection, outlier, data-imputation

I am doing univariate outlier detection in python. When I detect outliers for a variable, I know that the value should be whatever the highest non-outlier value is (i.e., the max if there were no outliers).

How can I impute this value in python or sklearn? I guess I can remove the values, get the max, replace the outliers and bring them back. But hoping there’s a function for that already.

Second, is this a bad idea? I see others remove the outlier completely or replace with the mean or median. I wonder if my approach is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My answer to the first question is use numpy's [percentile function](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.percentile.html). And then, with `y` being the target vector and `Tr` the percentile level chose,  try something like

```
import numpy as np
value = np.percentile(y, Tr)
for i in range(len(y)):
   if y[i] > value:
       y[i]= value
```

For the second question, I guess I would remove them or replace them with the mean if the outliers are an obvious mistake. But your approach seems reasonable otherwise.

Comment: Clean solution, thanks

Answer (score 2):

Are you values stored in a dataframe? You could use `.loc` to do this also.

`df.column_name.loc[df.column_name > max_value]  = max_value`